# Child component selector in *ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I have successfully implemented parent child Input-Output communication in angular.
I am passing current product in child

**parent.html**

```
 <tr *ngFor="let product of productList"> 
    <app-stock-popup *ngIf="product.isCheckInPopUp" (exitModalComp)="saveModalProductEntries($event)"
    [productChild]="product">
    </app-stock-popup>
    <button (click)="openChildComp()">Open Child </button>
    </tr>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
 openChildComp(product)
    {
    product.isCheckInPopUp = true;
    }
```

**Child.component.ts**

```
  @Input() productChild: ProductRow<ProductCategory, ProductItemDetails>;
  @Output() exitModalComp: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

//For emitting  Child comp
this.exitModalComp.emit(this.productChild);
```

**Now my question is** should I place child component selector inside or outside the loop.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let product of productList"> 

        </app-stock-popup>
        <button (click)="openChildComp()">Open Child </button>
        </tr>
   <app-stock-popup *ngIf="otherBoolean" (exitModalComp)="saveModalProductEntries($event)"
        [productChild]=" some input List">
```

Which approach is better and why?
 1. Does it take more memory in any way if i place selector inside *ngFor.
 2. Do HTML render as many times as items in *ngFor

My friend advised me to put selector outside *ngFor due to more memory taken by child or more HTML rendering.Is he right

My opinion is *ngIf removes the element(child) from DOM so both are same thing.

Need explanation.